# Deploying my front end and detecting client location by IP address - which AWS service should handle this? Confused by my options

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, geolocation

I'm still new to AWS and just following the documentation and asking questions here when I get stuck.  Please excuse me if this question sounds really noobish.

So far, I've deployed the following:

1. EB to deploy my REST API
2. RDS to deploy my psql database
3. Lambda functions to handle things like authentication & sending JWTs, uploading images to S3, etc.

I have got my basic back end (no caching (just started learning about redis), etc. set up yet, just the bare bones so far) deployed.

I'm still developing my front end, and have not even thought about how I will be deploying it yet (probably another deployment on EB, since I am using universal react).  I am just developing it locally but using my production env variables now so I am hitting my deployed API, etc.

**One of the MAJOR things I have no idea on how to do is detecting incoming requests from client side to get the client's location by IP address.  This is so that I can return the INITIAL results in your general location just like yelp, foursquare, etc. do when you go to to their sites.**

For now, I am just building a web app on desktop so I just want to worry about getting the IP address to get the general area of the user.  My use case is something similar to other sites you might have used which provides an INITIAL result set for things in your area (think foursquare or yelp).

Here are my questions:

1. What would be a good way to do this?  I'm thinking of handling this in my front end react universal deployment since it will be a node server with rendered page caching.  Is this a terrible idea?  It would work something like

   (1) request from client comes in

   (2) get IP from request and lookup the IP location using some service (still not sure what I'm going to use, have found a few plus a nodejs library called node-geoip).  Preferably, I can get the zip code since I am trying to save having to do so many queries by unique locations in my database, and instead return results in the zip code and the front end will show an initial map with the initial results in that zip code.

   (3) return to client the rendered page with those location params if it exists, otherwise create it, send it, and cache it.
2. Is the above a really dumb idea?  Maybe you have already done something like this, and could share your wisdom :)
3. Is there an AWS service which can already handle something like this for me?  Perhaps there's some functionality which can already do this.

Thanks.

AGAIN - I apologize if this is long winded.  I don't know anyone in real life who can help me and I feel alone :(.  I appreciate the help you guys can provide.

Comment: Location by IP is probably not going to be that useful, since many mobile devices have IP addresses that geolocate to a generic physical address related to the provider, which is often entirely unrelated to the device location and can be wrong by hundreds of miles.  A better answer is usually available from the device itself (including desktop browsers... don't ask how, you probably don't want to know) via the [geolocation api](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

Comment: AWS doesn't have any relevant geolocation services. There's CloudFront, which can block by country or pass the geolocated IP address's country code to your server as a header, e.g., `CloudFront-Viewer-Country: US`, but that's too coarse for your purposes... and Route 53 can customize DNS responses based on the country or based on what it believes to be the nearest AWS region to the browser from a set you select (e.g. modify response whether the user is nearest to us-west-2 or eu-central-1 or ap-southeast-1) so requests are delivered to your app's nearest deployment, but again, not useful here.

Comment: If the client connects directly to your app then you can retrieve the source IP from the request. If it comes via ELB, then it will be in x-forwarded-for HTTP header.

Comment: Thanks guys.  @Michael-sqlbot: I am using html5 geolocation in my front end, but that takes like 2-3 seconds to find the exact location.  I'm trying to cut down on that and somehow do what yelp or other services do - they give you results in your general area (like in your zip or something).

Comment: @jarmod: I haven't set up my ELB yet, but once that is set up what next?  I get the IP there, how do I pass that to whatever service to get the location?

Comment: There are numerous services like https://ipapi.co/ or https://www.whatismyip.com/ that provide APIs.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks.  Yes I understand, but I mean from the ELB, how do I actually call those API?  For example, would it fire a lambda function?  Or is it done in some other language?  Thank you

Comment: You are presumably writing an app server (or a Lambda function). Whichever it is and regardless of programming language, it can make API calls to other services, such as ipapi.co.

Comment: Ok awesome!  So I guess I was just confused.  So as soon as I get a `req` I can see how to figure this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. **Getting the user's IP address**.  You mentioned you're using 'EB' - I presume you mean AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer)? If so, then you need to read the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header in your app code, since otherwise what you'll really detect is the *ELB*'s IP address. X-Forwarded-For contains the user's real IP - or rather, the IP of the end-connection being made (there's no telling if this is really a VPN, Proxy or something else-- but it's as far as you can get with an IP.)
2. **Querying an IP DB that can turn the addr into a location object**.  There are tons of libraries for you. Assuming you're using Node, you can use `node-geoip` as you mentioned. Or you can just search 'geoip service' on Google and find managed services, like [Telize](https://market.mashape.com/fcambus/telize/) on Mashape. If you don't want to manage the DB lookup yourself or keep the thing up to date, then a managed service would help.

In either case, it's likely that you'll be doing asynchronous look-ups. In that case, you might want to use `async/await` to get the user's full object before injecting that into your React props and ultimately rendering it as a HTML string that's sent down to the client.

You could also use a library like [redial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redial) to decorate your components with data requirements, and return a Promise you can await on to know when you're okay to render.

Since you probably want to enable client routing too (i.e. where the user can click on a route in their browser, and the server isn't touched at all), then you will probably need some way to retrieve the IP address/results based on that IP even when the server isn't involved in the initial render.

For that, you could write a REST service that retrieves the results. Or write a GraphQL back-end that gets the data. It doesn't matter how you write it, since the server will have access to the `X-Forwarded-For` header and can use that to retrieve the results and send back location-aware data.

FYI, I'm writing a React starter kit (called [ReactNow](https://github.com/leebenson/reactnow)) that uses [rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) for handling async streams. It's not ready yet, but it might help you figure out the code layout that would offer a balanced mix between rendering on the server, and writing universal code that requires some heavy lifting from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed write up!  EB as in elastic beanstalk :(

Comment: Yes its a lot to think about.  Honestly the only part I feel comfortable on right now is react and javascript.  I have no clue on the "how the rest of it works" which I what I'm trying to learn!  I appreciate your detailed writeup.  Is it a bad idea to use elastic beanstalk to deploy my universal application server?   I thought if I do that, then I can also put ELB in front of it and figure out later how to communicate with the IP db services.